# How would you do this SQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's assume I have 3 tables in a MySQL table with the following fields.

### product

```
product_id
product_name
```

### category

```
category_id
category_name
```

### product_in_category

```
product_in_category_id
product_id
category_id
```

What query would you recommend to get a list of all products that are not currently assigned to a category in the "product_in_category" table?

Performance is very important, these tables are huge.

Comment: If performance is very important, then product_in_category should have category_id not category_name.

Comment: totally right, there is an error there, fixing it now.

Comment: Note that some of the answers below (including mine) assume that product_in_category.category_id can't be null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select a.* from product a
left join product_in_category b on a.product_id = b.product_id
where b.product_id is null
```

Answer (score 5):

### Using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL:

```
   SELECT p.*
     FROM PRODUCT p
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_IN_CATEGORY pic ON pic.product_id = p.product_id
    WHERE pic.product_in_category_id IS NULL
```

### Using NOT IN

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM PRODUCT p
 WHERE p.product_id NOT IN (SELECT pic.product_id
                              FROM PRODUCT_IN_CATEGORY pic)
```

### Using NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM PRODUCT p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM PRODUCT_IN_CATEGORY pic
                    WHERE pic.product_id = p.product_id)
```

### Which is best?

It depends on if the columns being compared are nullable (values can be NULL) or not.  If they are [nullable, then NOT IN/NOT EXISTS are more efficient](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).  If the columns are [***not*** nullable, then LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is more efficient (MySQL only)](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).

Answer (score 3):

I would use left join.

If you look around you can find answers that include not in and not exists.

```
SELECT
  p.product_id, 
  product_name
FROM
   product p
   left join product_in_category pc
   on p.product_id = pc.product_id
WHERE
 pc.product_id is null
```

Comment: +1 the left join / is null works great for this sort of thing for our DB, and the tables are millions of rows. However, you want IS NULL not IS NOT NULL

Comment: I think you want IS NULL instead of IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 3):

There are basically three methods to do that:

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    product p
LEFT JOIN
        product_in_category pc
ON      pc.product_id = pc.product_id
WHERE   pc.product_id IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    product p
WHERE   product_id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  product_id
        FROM    product_in_category
        )
```

or

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    product p
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    product_in_category pc
        WHERE   pc.product_id = p.product_id
        )
```

As long as `product_in_category.product_id` is indexed, they all are nice, but `LEFT JOIN` and `NOT IN` are a little bit more efficient.

See this article for performance comparison:

- [**NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT product_id
from products p
 where not exists (select 1
                   from product_in_category pc
                   where pc.product_id = p.product_id)
```

Comment: I dunno about MySql, but in SqlServer this is the best option, since use Anti-semi-join

Comment: +1 for NOT EXISTS, which can perform better. See [here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Product_name from Product
WHERE ProductID not in (SELECT product_id FROM product_in_category)
```

Comment: in Oracle I would use MINUS.  this one would be my second pick (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Exclusive joins are always performance hogs.  Here's a link that may help with mysql exclusive joins:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/

HTH